# MySQL Query, WHERE IN, AND date BETWEEN ? AND?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query works up until I try to limit it a bit more by adding a date range
where clientid in with the implode function works well. But I can't figure out how to add the date range limit in here.

Every time I add

```
STR_TO_DATE(date, \'%m/%d/%Y\') BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

To

```
SELECT invid, packid, clientid, date_range_start, date_range_end, value 
FROM inv_packs 
WHERE clientid IN (' . implode(',', $in) . ')
```

It breaks

I've been roaming around trying to find these two being used together as an example, and have been going back and forth trying different things to get this to work but no luck, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the full simplified code for the query:

```
$l = count($uniqueIds);
$types = 'ss';
$types .= str_repeat('i', $l);

$num_of_invoices = count($invoice_table_data);
$inv_pack_count = 0;

$in = array_fill(0, count($uniqueIds), '?');

$query_inv_packs_for_date_range = 'SELECT invid, packid, clientid, date_range_start, date_range_end, value FROM inv_packs WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, \'%m/%d/%Y\') BETWEEN ? AND ? AND clientid IN (' . implode(',', $in) . ')';

if($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_inv_packs_for_date_range)){
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, $types, $filter_min_date, $filter_max_date, ...$uniqueIds);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $invoice_id, $pack_id, $client_id_from_inv_pack_table, $date_range_start, $date_range_end, $value);

      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2)){
           $invoice_packs_table_data[$inv_pack_count]['date_range_start'] = $date_range_start;
           $inv_pack_count++;

           echo " " . $date_range_start;

       }
       print_r($invoice_packs_table_data);
       $stmt2->close();
}
```

Comment: Make sure your variables contain the proper format for your DATE or DATETIME field.  MySql will not accept anything then that perfect format.

Comment: I would like you to confirm that all the data in the `date` field column is definitely in the `%m/%d/%Y` format. Please also provide some date samples to get sense of how date values are stored in the db.

Comment: I would like to see your `date` column wrapped in back ticks. Can you unpack `...` into `bind_param` like that?  You might rather use pdo.

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain and store dates as dates

Comment: All the dates are definitely in %m/%d/%Y format. All date fields are in text Datatypes. Also I have tested unpacking ... into bind_param and it was working until I tried adding that date range that I needed to limit.

Answer (score 0):

simple variable error on my end, but the syntax for this MySQL query was correct.
Wish there was some emojis here to roll my eyes way back.